# что(,) Я считаю, должно быть сделано

Tags: запятые

Нужна она – запят.?

`Я делаю только тО, что(,) Я считаю, должно быть сделано.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна:

***Я делаю только то, что, я считаю, должно быть сделано.***

Опять же, говорим о корректности.

Вводное предложение ***я считаю*** можно опустить без потери структуры:

*Я делаю то, что должно быть сделано*.

Не ставя, не сделать структуру не испорченной, потому что без запятой образуется придаточная часть ***что я считаю***, а придаточные можно вынуть из предложения, опять же, без потери структуры. Но в предложении без запятой так не получится, потому что получится белиберда:

*Я делаю то, должно быть сделано*, —

а если придаточное вынуть нельзя, то предложение сразу неправильное.

---

Вывод: запятая нужна.